# Is that possible to write dynamic code for Salesforce SOAP to use object like map?

Tags: soap, sobject

For regular SObject, I can run the following code:

```
static void x(Map<String, String> fieldValuesMap) {

    SObject so;

    for (String key: fieldValuesMap.keySet() ) {

          so.put( key, fieldValuesMap.get(value) );

     }

    insert so;

}
```

However, when I try to do the same thing with SOAP SObject

```
static void x(Map<String, String> fieldValuesMap) {

    sobjectEnterpriseSoapSforceCom.sObject_x so;

    for (String key: fieldValuesMap.keySet() ) {

          so.put( key, fieldValuesMap.get(value) );

     }

    insert so;

}
```

the last one raises an exception

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature:
>   [sobjectEnterpriseSoapSforceCom.Account].put(String)

Is it possible to dynamically fill field values for SObject in SOAP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as "[reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html)" in Apex Code, so if you want to write the fields dynamically, you'd have to write your own set method, which would kind of defeat the purpose.

However, you *might* be able to get away with using JSON:

```
sobjectEnterpriseSoapSforceCom.sObject_x so = (sobjectEnterpriseSoapSforceCom.sObject_x)
    JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(fieldValuesMap),
    sobjectEnterpriseSoapSforceCom.sObject_x.class);
```

However, even in that case, you might also need to copy some internal state, so you'd end up having to initialize a refresh copy of sObject_x, convert it to a Map via JSON.deserialize, then use Map.putAll to write the new fieldValuesMap into the new map, then deserialize back into the object again.

```
Map<String, Object> temp = (Map<String, Object>)
    JSON.serialize(sobjectEnterpriseSoapSforceCom.sObject_x);
temp.putAll((Map<String, Object>)fieldValuesMap);

sobjectEnterpriseSoapSforceCom.sObject_x so = (sobjectEnterpriseSoapSforceCom.sObject_x)
    JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(temp),
    sobjectEnterpriseSoapSforceCom.sObject_x.class);
```

I hope this helps you, but as I said, it's probably going to be a very messy affair.